# iOS JSON Parse into NSDictionary and then NSArray with SBJson

Tags: ios, json, parsing, sbjson

It should be so simple but I cannot get it work.

Json response is
([{"id":"1", "x":"1", "y":"2"},{"id":2, "x":"2", "y":"4"}])

```
NSString *response = [request responseString];
//response is ([{"id":"1", "x":"1", "y":"2"},{"id":2, "x":"2", "y":"4"}])

SBJSON *parser = [[[SBJSON alloc] init] autorelease];

NSDictionary *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:response error:NULL];
// jsonObject doesn't have any value here..Am I doing something wrong?

NSMutableArray Conversion = [jsonObject valueForKey:NULL];
//Even if I get the value of jsonObject. I don't know what to put for valueForKey here
```

Conversion shoud have two NSObjects..and each of them should have like

id:1
x:1
y:2

and

id:2
x:2
y:4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your JSON parser will produce an NSArray from your response string, not an NSDictionary.  Note that JSON parsers, including SBJSON, will return either an array object or a dictionary object, depending on the contents of the json that is being parsed.

```
NSArray *jsonObject = [parser objectWithString:response error:nil];
```

You can then access the individual items in your array (the array elements will be of type NSDictionary) and use `valueForKey:` to get the properties of each item.

```
NSDictionary *firstItem = [jsonObject objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *theID = [firstItem objectForKey:@"id"];
```

Comment: Tried and got invalid CFArrayRef for jsonObject..It seems that jsonObject is not getting anything.. I checked with breakpoint and able to see parser got json value..

Comment: I got it.. Your answer was perfect :) but Json return I got has ( and ) so parser cannot process it.. I have removed with       response = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]; and response = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""]; ** and then it's working perfect.. thanks.. :) Is there some easy way to remove '(' and ')' at a time?